# How to keep watching variables and their values in VS Code Debugging Session?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

So I've been writing a program in C and debugging to solve the problems I had. After I solved those problems, I could not watch the values of the variables since debugging session just quits because there are no errors or breakpoints after I solved the problems occurred previously.

My editor is Visual Studio Code, running it on macOS, GCC.

Comment: Did you mark a breakpoint? try with F5 button to access the debug.

Answer (score 3):

You should basicely put breakpoints at the end of your code, for example on the `return` line.

If you just want to know which values your variables have at the end of the execution, you can put `printf("%x", your_variable); //DEBUG` for the variables you want to see, and remove these lines when you finished debugging.

Moreover, if you're familiar with prompt commands, I recommand you to install gdb, this debugger is very powerful and easy to use ! [Here is a little tutorial if you're interested ;)](http://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial/how-use-gdb)

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a more efficient way to keep the debug session running without setting arbitrary breakpoints? I want to keep the debug session active while working on a single file and watch what happens to my objects.

Answer (score 2):

Set your breakpoint on the code then press F5 to run the app in VSCode. Once the breakpoint hit, you can see local variables by selecting `Run and Debug` button (Red). You alse can add variables into `Watch`...

[image]